# Write a Java program using single dimensional array. Have a list of 10 numbers and fetch a value based on the index

Tags: java, arrays, fetch

So I have this assignment for my Programming class, and I'm lost on what to do for the second part.  This is the code I have so far:

```
    class SingleArray
    {
      public static void main(String[]args)
      {
        int[] b=new int[]{5,10,15,20,25,30,35,40,45,50};
```

Not much I know, but I really am confused on how I would get it to fetch the different array values.  Do I have to import the util scanner to do this?  Any help to point me in the right direction?  Thanks guys!

Comment: Break down the big problem into little problems: 1) how to prompt the user and get input, and 2) with the input get and return the value based on index.

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/arrays.html

Comment: (Off-topic) *Close* your teacher's assignment. It's unclear.

Answer (score 2):

To access an index `i` in `int[] b`, you use: `b[i]`.  For example:

```
System.out.println(b[i]); //prints the int at index i

b[i] = 5; //assigns 5 to index i
b[i] = x; //assigns an int x, to index i

int y = b[i];  //assigns b[i] to y
```

To search through the array for a number `x`:

```
for (int i = 0; i < b.length; i++)
{
     if (b[i] == x)
     {
         //doSomething
     }
}
```

There are also auxiliary methods provided by the Java [Arrays](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html) class.

Here's a [tutorial on arrays](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/arrays.html), here's an additional [Java Language Basics tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/index.html).

Answer (score 0):

Please do the assignments in the comments below-

```
class SingleArray {

 // Declare an array of 10 integers. 
 // Assignment: Why did I declare it as static?
 private static int[] array = new int[] { 5, 10, 15, 20, 25, 30, 35, 40, 45, 50 };

 // A method that returns the value at a given index from the array
 // Assignment: Why the method below is static?
 private static int getValue(int index){

     return array[index];

 }    

 public static void main(String[] args){

    for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++){

        int valueAtIndex = getValue(i);

        System.out.println("Index: " + (i + 1) + " Value: " + valueAtIndex);

        // Assignment: remove the statement "int valueAtIndex = getValue(i);" and 
        // modify the System.out.println statement to have the same result 

    }

  }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
List<Integer> integerList=new ArrayList<Integer>();
for(int i=0;i<10;i++){
 integerList.add(i);
}
//you can fetch the values by using this method:
integerList.get(valueIndex);
```

Answer (score 0):

This might help:

```
public class OneDimensionalArrays {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        //initialize an array num with the respective values
        int []num={5,10,15,20,25,30,35,40,45,50};

        // The looping will work within the range of the array.
        for (int i = 0; i<num.length;i++){

            System.out.println("Enter the index to find the value of ");

            //To catch array index out of bound exception
            try{
                Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
                //Save the user inputted value in indexValue variable

                int indexValue = sc.nextInt();
                // Enter 100 to terminate the program execution
                if (indexValue != 100) {
                    System.out.println("Value in the respective index of array is " + num[indexValue]);
                }
                else{
                    System.out.println("Program has been terminated by user");
                    break;
                                    }
            }
            catch (Exception e ){
                System.out.println("Enter the index within range of the array");
            }
        }
    }
}
```